# How to keep in touch with former colleagues

Tags: communication, new-job, conversation, ex-colleagues

After more than ten years I started a new job last summer, so it´s been near on half a year in my new job. I absolutely love my new job and like my new colleagues.

I liked my former colleagues, too. There´s not a single person I liked so much to call them a real friend, but it was the team as a whole that I really liked.

Though we said we´ll keep in touch and I met two of those colleagues incidentally while shopping, I feel contact has broken up. I´d absolutely like to fix that. I feel somewhat awkward simply calling someone, though. To get them all (or some of them) together to talk I´d have to rely on someone "inside" my former employer to organise, e.g. going out for a drink, and I don´t know how to start such a conversation.

**Am I right about feeling awkward? If not: How should I start communication? Is it even usual what I´m intending?**

I´ve got mobile numbers of most of them - and most of them have WhatsApp. During work hours I can´t call, because of strict rules in their company. Either way: should I call or write?

The goal on my side of contacting them: I´d love to exchange work experiences. What moved for them, what do we work like where I am now, I think I can even solve at least one of their (minor) issues we had with my new experiences, which I would love to talk about. I just like to chat about work here and there. Like we always did when I still worked there.

Side notes:

- For my former colleagues things aren´t going so well as we´re running towards recession and my former employer has already been hit, meaning pay cuts etc. for my former colleagues - while my new employer usually gets soaring during national recession. I gave in notice before word of recession was spreading. I´m somewhat gleeing inside, but don´t want to be harsh on them.
- my current company isn´t looking for new employees (in our specific job) neither, so should we meet it will be no job board for either side. Just exchanging experiences
- one of my former colleagues (with whom I was working most of the time) sees me as a traitor because I left. He´s a former military valuing "loyalty" pretty high. I´m pretty sad about that as we worked pretty close for several years, but I will (have to) accept if he doesn´t want to talk to me anymore.
- some of my former colleagues kept visiting each other at home, and I sometimes participated. So inviting them to my home would for sure be the simplest way to get in touch. But I was the only female in the department, I´m married and my husband made it clear, even when I still worked there, he doesn´t want them here. I respect his opinion, especially since there´s one colleague that likes drinking and likes staying overnight wherever he is, which even I would find awkward. So inviting them here is no option. But of course I can´t invite them to someone else´s home...

PS: I thought about posting that question to interpersonal instead. Tell me if it´s better off there.

Comment: Isn't this not just the way of things? We are colleagues we get along, maybe have some social interaction now and again but then we leave to a new place and we loose touch.

Comment: Ask yourself how you would feel if a former coworker you were friendly with randomly called you to catch up. Would feel pretty good, right?

Comment: Just do it. Don't overthink it. Drinks, coffee, BBQ, poker, etc. It's all perfectly normal.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not comfortable for e-mail/ call / text / in-person meeting to start with,  professional networking sites are made just for cases like this. One of the most widely used sites is [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login).

If you're friends with them more than in a professional setup, you can consider inviting / adding them in your personal social networking sites, too. Then, based on your level of comfort, you can start calling them up or invite for a meeting in a cafe / restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

**Of course you should keep in touch** with your former colleagues if you want. It's absolutely nothing to feel awkward about. Quite the opposite: this is important "social capital."

For those who live in the same city/region, pick a date, time, and venue (pub? restaurant?).  Announce a get-together by text / email / linkedin / whatever and ask people to pass it along to others they know.

I worked for one place that was acquired (Apollo Computer, Inc). For years afterward we had an annual get-together. It got big enough that we had to make an arrangement with a local hotel to use their biggest meeting room. (The hotel charged for a bunch of snack foods, and there was a cash bar.) It was great. You can do the same.

It's a valuable networking opportunity for those who need something new to do. And, it's great to hear what your old co-workers are up to.